# No address space for Linux Kernel threads

Tags: multithreading, memory, linux-kernel

Why the Linux kernel threads do not have an address space. For any task to execute, it should have a memory region right? Where do the text and data of kernel threads go?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Kernel threads do have an address space. It's just that they all share the same one. This does not prevent them from each having a different stack.

Text and data are laid out in the kernel address space (the one that is shared by all the threads), depending on how and when it was allocated, and what it's used for.

The [Linux MM](http://linux-mm.org/) site has a lot of documentation about this aspect of Linux. Head over there.

Comment: Thanks. I got it. So Linux Kernel threads do not have a separate address space and they share the same address space of kernel.

Comment: Just like any other thread in any other OS, be it in the kernel or not. One point of using threads is their property of having a common address space. If you want to have something with different address spaces, you need to use processes.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the precise answer, because I'm not a Linux architect.

But in general, so-called kernel threads *do* have an address space: it is the address space which contains the kernel.  It might not need to be explicitly represented for each kernel thread, since it is shared among many threads.

I'd expect any real thread implementation to have a machine context block containing register values (and stack pointer, etc.), and a pointer to a the address space in which the thread is supposed to run.  Then a scheduler, starting a ready thread, can easily determine whether the memory management unit is set up to enable access to the address space (and if not, set it up) to enable the thread to run in its desired space.

Comment: Thanks. But i am afraid i find your answer too complex. I have just started studying the Linux Kernel Development. May be in the coming chapters i will able to answer my doubt.

Comment: Thanks. Now I get what you meant after reading Mat's answer :)